# How to enable scrolling?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have the following layout. When changing the textviews via code, they expand and what was below is now cut off. This is intended. But I cannot scroll, moving my finger from bottom to top does not change the view even though "scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"" is enabled. How to enable scrolling?

EDIT: Working solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/scrollView1">
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="vertical"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
        p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        p1:background="#005C2E"
        p1:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        p1:scrollbars="vertical"
        p1:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay">
        <TextView
            p1:text="Text"
            p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:id="@+id/textView1"
            p1:textSize="22sp"
            p1:textColor="#00005C" />
        <TextView
            p1:text="Text"
            p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:textSize="22sp"
            p1:textColor="#5C0000"
            p1:id="@+id/textView2" />
        <TextView
            p1:textSize="22sp"
            p1:text="Text"
            p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:textColor="#00005C"
            p1:id="@+id/textView3" />
        <TextView
            p1:textSize="22sp"
            p1:text="Text"
            p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
            p1:textColor="#5C0000"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:id="@+id/textView4" />
        <TextView
            p1:textSize="22sp"
            p1:text="Text"
            p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:textColor="#00005C"
            p1:id="@+id/textView5" />
        <TextView
            p1:textSize="22sp"
            p1:text="Text"
            p1:textColor="#5C0000"
            p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:id="@+id/textView6" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Host your linearlayout inside a [scrollview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

The doc says:

> Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the container of your `TextView` inside of a `ScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
p1:orientation="vertical"
p1:minWidth="25px"
p1:minHeight="25px"
p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
p1:background="#005C2E"
p1:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
p1:scrollbars="vertical"
p1:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay">
<TextView
    p1:text="Text"
    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/textView1"
    p1:textSize="22sp"
    p1:textColor="#00005C" />
<TextView
    p1:text="Text"
    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:textSize="22sp"
    p1:textColor="#5C0000"
    p1:id="@+id/textView2" />
<TextView
    p1:textSize="22sp"
    p1:text="Text"
    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:textColor="#00005C"
    p1:id="@+id/textView3" />
<TextView
    p1:textSize="22sp"
    p1:text="Text"
    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    p1:textColor="#5C0000"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/textView4" />
<TextView
    p1:textSize="22sp"
    p1:text="Text"
    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:textColor="#00005C"
    p1:id="@+id/textView5" />
<TextView
    p1:textSize="22sp"
    p1:text="Text"
    p1:textColor="#5C0000"
    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/textView6" />
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There was something wrong with your code in line 3. I edited my text with the working code.

Comment: Great, I glad you have figured it out.